powerdns recurser and pihole with docker
I'm trying to setup powerdns-recursor and pihole in docker.
I have the following docker-compose.yml and this recursor.conf
services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    environment:
      TZ: 'MyCity/MyCountry'  # e.g., 'America/New_York'
      WEBPASSWORD: '<PASSWORD>'  # Set your web interface password
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 1.1.1.1
    ports:
      - '53:53/tcp'
      - '53:53/udp'
      - '80:80'
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - my_custom_network

  powerdns:
    container_name: powerdns
    image: powerdns/pdns-recursor-51
    volumes:
      - './recursor.conf:/etc/powerdns/recursor.conf'
    ports:
      - '5354:53/tcp'
      - '5354:53/udp'
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - my_custom_network

networks:
  my_custom_network:
    driver: bridge


local-address=0.0.0.0
local-address=[::]
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/recursor.d
forward-zones-recurse=.=1.1.1.1
allow-from=<my network's IP>/24
loglevel=9

Unfortunately, when i check docker logs pihole I have this error message:
  [✗] DNS resolution is currently unavailable
I can run dig @localhost example.com but can't run dig @localhost -p 5354 example.com, which is also telling me the powerdns container isn't working as a dns server because port 5354 isn't mapping to 53 in the container.
The output I get for dig @localhost example.com``` is this:
;; communications error to ::1#5354: timed out
;; communications error to ::1#5354: timed out
;; communications error to ::1#5354: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#5354: timed out

; <<>> DiG 9.18.24-1-Debian <<>> @localhost -p 5354 example.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached

